# How can I select a record in a ListView and reference it in the code behind method?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm listing records from my `ListItem` tables in my SQLite database in a `ListView`, and each record is its own button, which leads to an `EditItem` method. All I want to do in this method is set the boolean `Large` attribute for the `ListItem` to `false`, but I'm having trouble getting the corresponding `ListItem` as a variable.

With my current code, the error I'm getting is:

> Error CS0266   Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to
>   'Myapp.Models.ListItem'. An explicit conversion exists (are you
>   missing a cast?)

What's the correct way to get and update the selected record in my code behind?

### **UPDATE**

I tried using a Command with my button, and now I don't get any errors, but the `EditItem` method isn't even called. I now know how to pass parameters with the `Command` property, but I'm not sure how to call a method with it. I know how to call a method with the `Clicked` property, but I don't know how to pass parameters with it.

**Xaml:**

```
    <ListView>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Button Text="{Binding Name}" Command="EditItem" CommandParameters="{Binding}" VerticalOptions="Start"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

**C# Code Behind:**

```
    public async void EditItem(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListItem item = (ItemList)sender as ItemList;
        item.Large = false;
        ...
    }
```

I'm using the sqlite-net-pcl Nuget package in a Xamarin.forms app.

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `ListItem item = (ListItem)e.SelectedItem;`.

Right now you are trying to assign a generic `object` to a `ListItem` type, you should tell it what type it is.

You probably want some safeguards in there to make sure it is actually a `ListItem` object. I.e.:

```
var selectedListItem = e.SelectedItem as ListItem;

if (selectedListItem == null)
{
    // TODO inform user or something
    return;
}
```

In accordance with what you are looking for according to your comments, I will elaborate a bit more. For what you want to do, its best to use the `Command` and `CommandParameter` on the `Button`. There is one thing to note here. For the `Command` on the `Button`, you probably want to execute code from your view model. But the scope within one `ViewCell` is that of a `ListItem`. To make sure the `Command` is being searched for in the right place, give the `Page` a name, i.e. like this: `<ContentPage xmlns="..." x:Name="MyPage">`.

Now from the `Button` go like this: `<Button Text="{Binding Name}" Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference MyPage}, Path=BindingContext.EditItem}" CommandParameters="{Binding .}" VerticalOptions="Start"/>`. This tells the button to set the source of the binding for the `Command` to the page with name `MyPage`. The actual source of the binding is then set to the `BindingContext.EditItem` property. If you're not using a separate view model but just use the code-behind, omit the `BindingContext.` part.

The last thing you need to do is add the actual `Command`. In your view model (or in the code-behind) add a property: `public Command EditItem { get; set; }` and add the executable code in the constructor or how else you would like to initialize it:

```
public MyPage()
{
    EditItem = new Command((parameter) => {
        ListItem item = (ItemList)parameter as ItemList;

        if (item == null)
            return; // TODO error handling

        item.Large = false;
    });
}
```

Because of the `BindingParameter` on your `Button`, which is set to `.`, meaning that it is bound to the actual object that is behind that `ViewCell`, you will retrieve the `ListItem` as the parameter.

You probably want to move the `Command` code into a separate method for readability. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I think the record itself isn't being passed through, because I'm getting this error now: `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` Is there something I should add to `Clicked="EditItem"` to specify the record I want to edit?

Comment: Ah I see. You probably want to use a command with the commandparameter then

Comment: Do you know how I could do that?

Comment: I switched to a Command and set the CommandParameter="{Binding}", but I still can't get the record in the code-behind. Either it's not passing through or I'm not retrieving it properly.

Comment: Update: The method in the code-behind isn't even being called. Do you know how to call a method with a Command?

Comment: Sorry it took a while, it was night time here :) Updated my answer for Commands

Comment: Thank you so much, I never would have figured this out!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could be of service!

Comment: Would you happen to know how I could make the "EditItem" method asynchronous?

Comment: Sure, just add async to the `EditItem` method signature and/or in 'newing' the `Command`, i.e.:  `new Command(async (parameter) => {`